# GetMapping not working for Nest client in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest

perhaps some of the documentation http://nest.azurewebsites.net/ is old because i'm running into a at least few issues...

i've got a json object 'search'. i am getting null returned from the GetMapping function. well, it returns a Nest.RootObjectMapping object, but all fields within are null. i can get the mapping fine using Sense or regular curl.

```
var mapping = elasticClient.GetMapping<MyJsonPOCO>();
```

any ideas?

also, just as example of other things going wrong, this search works, but adding 'fields' to it does not (i got the fields declaration per the documentation)

```
var result = elasticClient.Search<MyJsonPOCO>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .OnField(e => e.Title)
                        .Query("my search term"))));
```

if i use this query with the fields added (to just return 'title'), i get a json parser issue.

```
var result = elasticClient.Search<MyJsonPOCO>(s => s
                .Fields(f => f.Title)
                .Query(q => q
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .OnField(e => e.Title)
                        .Query("my search term"))));
```

here's the error for that one:
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'hits.hits[0].fields.title', line 1, position 227.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch 1.0 changed the way fields are returned in the search response

You need the NEST 1.0 beta1 release to work with Elasticsearch 1.0

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/introducing-elasticsearch-net-nest-1-0-0-beta1/

See also this github issue for more background information on the why and how to work with fields from 1.0 forward:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/590

Comment: that makes a lot more sense! thanks. i don't know how i missed that. marking as answer.